# Indicate the set of all $x$ satisfying the following conditions $(x+1)(x-1)(x-2) > 0$ Solution check

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Indicate the  set of all $x$ satisfying the following conditions: $$(x+1)(x-1)(x-2) > 0$$

One of the sets is $$(2, \infty)$$
I'm more concerned about obtaining the second set. A solution says $$(-1,1)$$, but I don't see how that is possible unless there was a typo in the text and the author meant $$(1-x)(x-1)(x-2) > 0$$ as the question.

Comment: $(-1,1)$ is right for the question as given. As a test, calculate the function for some $x$ between $-1$ and $1$. Using $x=0$ is good.

Comment: Then how do you obtain that interval? Because simple manipulation is not producing it.

Comment: The candidates for where there is a change in sign are the places where $f(x)=0$. By inspection the roots are $x=-1, 1, 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a product of three real numbers to be positive.  That only occurs if all three are positive or two terms are negative the third is positive.  (One negative, or all three negative result in the product being negative.)

$x - 2 < x - 1 < x + 1$ so all are positive when $x+ 1> x - 1 > x - 2 > 0 \iff x > 2$ so $(2, \infty)$ is one interval.

To get one term positive and two negative you need $x + 1 > 0 > x-1 > x-2$>  In other words $x+1 > 0$ and $x -1 < 0$ or in other words $x > -1$ and $x < 1$.  So $(-1,1)$ is the other interval.

===

or another way to think of it:

There are three spots, $x - 2 = 0$, $x -1 = 0$, and $x + 1 = 0$ where the signs of the terms change polarity.  So we only need to consider the intervals: $(-\infty, -1),(-1,1),(1,2)$ and $(2, \infty)$.  By direct application we can see two result in negative products and two in positive.

Comment: While I know what you mean, please check the formatting of your answer.

Comment: Check what about the formatting of my answer?

Comment: You just fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

$(-1, 1)$ is indeed the second set.

When $-1<x<1$, the first factor $(x+1)$ will be positive and the next two factors will be negative. A positive number multiplied by two negatives nets a positive number, thus an x in this range will produce a positive product.

Answer (score 2):

$(x+1)(x-1)(x-2) = 0$ when $x \in \{-1,1,2\}$

When $x<-1,$$\\
(x+1)<0\\
(x-1)<0\\
(x-2)<0$

Negative* negative * negative  is negative.

When $-1<x<1,$$\\
(x+1)>0\\
(x-1)<0\\
(x-2)<0$

positive * negative * negative  is positive.

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Building a plot can help you a lot.

[image: graph_plot]